# sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier more depth less accuracy?

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have two learned `sklearn.tree.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier`s. Both are trained with the same *training data*. Both learned with different *maximum depths* for the decision trees. The depth for the `decision_tree_model` was `6` and the depth for the `small_model` was `2`. Besides the `max_depth`, no other parameters were specified.

When I want to get the *accuracy on the training data* of them both like this:

```
small_model_accuracy = small_model.score(training_data_sparse_matrix, training_data_labels)
decision_tree_model_accuracy = decision_tree_model.score(training_data_sparse_matrix, training_data_labels)
```

Surprisingly the output is:

```
small_model accuracy: 0.61170212766
decision_tree_model accuracy: 0.422496238986
```

How is this even possible? Shouldn't a tree with a higher maximum depth always have a higher accuracy on the *training data* when learned with the same training data? Is it maybe that `score` function, which outputs the `1 - accuracy` or something?

**EDIT**:

- I just tested it with even higher maximum depth. The value returned becomes even lower. This hints at it being `1 - accuracy` or something like that.

**EDIT#2**:

It seems to be a mistake I made with working with the training data. I thought about the whole thing again and concluded: *"Well if the depth is higher, the tree shouldn't be the reason for this. What else is there? The training data itself. But I used the same data! Maybe I did something to the training data in between?"*
Then I checked again and there is a difference in how I use the training data. I need to transform it from an SFrame into a scipy matrix (might have to be sparse too). Now I made another accuracy calculation right after fitting the two models. This one results in 61% accuracy for the `small_model` and 64% accuracy for the `decision_tree_model`. That's only 3% more and still somewhat surprising, but at least it's possible.

**EDIT#3**:

The problem is resolved. I handled the training data in a wrong way and that resulted in different fitting.

Here is the plot of accuracy after fixing the mistakes:

[image: Decision Tree Accuracy]

This looks correct and would also explain why the assignment creators chose to choose 6 as the maximum depth.

Comment: Is there a reason why you specified `max_depth`? If you put None, the algorithm will try to expand nodes as needed (roughly speaking). Also, can you inform other parameters you may have set, such as `min_samples_split` and `max_leaf_nodes`, that might be important?

Comment: @tuliocasagrande There is a reason. It is part of the assignment of an online course to set the depth to 2 and 6 for those models. No other parameters have been specified, I'll add this info to the question.

Comment: Since you are using the training data, the lower accuracy also puzzles me. The only thing I can say is that `score()` is just a bypass to [accuracy_score()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) and the output is not a `1 - accuracy` as you thought. Internally it just does a `score = y_true == y_pred`.

Comment: @tuliocasagrande Hm ok thanks for that info, maybe it'll help me finding the issue.

Comment: @Zelphir, there is something weird going on here. You should consider posting your full source code and data if possible.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester It's definitely possible and I'd like to do so, I have all of it in a Jupyter notebook and could upload that, but I am not sure if that's OK with the online course. It's a Coursera course and they have a codex not to share solutions of assignments or taking solutions of others.

I can try to add all code relevant, so that it cannot be seen as a solution to a specific problem, though.

Comment: It may be worth your time to see if you can reproduce this problem on other ([perhaps smaller and publicly available](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/#toy-datasets)) datasets, so that you can perhaps share a minimal working example here.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester Thanks for hinting at those datasets. I am only doing binary classification for now, so I guess I'd have to use the _digits_ dataset. However I do not understand yet how to use that dataset once I loaded it. Maybe I'll try again if nothing else helps. A lot of machine learning seems to be to know how to handle the data you get and what structure it has. With the digits dataset I couldn't figure that out yet.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't a tree with a higher maximum depth always have a higher
>   accuracy when learned with the same training data?

No, definitely not always. The problem is you're overfitting your model to your training data in fitting a more complex tree. Hence, the lower score as increase the maximum depth.

Comment: And what if that value `score` returns is smaller with a higher depth for the _training data_ (not validation data!) as well? Doesn't that not hint at overfitting?

Comment: The OP is training and testing in the *same training data*. Over-fitting here shouldn't be a problem (in fact, when testing = training data, over-fitting is desirable).

Comment: @imaluengo, the term over-fitting only makes sense when you have a cost measure on both training data and out-of-sample data as model fitting progresses.